# DateRange search is not working in Elastic search NEST api

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a table of logs records and I want to conduct a simple search by date.

For example, I wanted to search all the queries before 01.06.2019 00:00:00 (mm.DD.yyyy hh:mm:ss) and I wrote this query:

```
var query = client.Search<SearchEventDto>(s => s
                .AllIndices()
                .AllTypes()
                .Query(q => q
                    .MatchAll() && +q
                    .DateRange(r =>r
                        .Field(f => f.timestamp)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2019,06,01, 0, 0, 0))
                    )
                )
            );
```

My Dto looks like this:

```
 public class SearchEventDto : IDto
    {
        [KendoColumn(Hidden = true, Editable = true)]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [KendoColumn(Order = 2, DisplayName = "Level")]
        public string level { get; set; }
        [KendoColumn(Order = 4, DisplayName = "Message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [KendoColumn(Hidden = true)]
        public string host { get; set; }
        [KendoColumn(Order = 3, DisplayName = "Source")]
        public string src { get; set; }

        [KendoColumn(Order = 1, DisplayName = "Timestamp", UIType = UIType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

        [KendoColumn(Hidden = true)]
        public DateTime time { get; set; }

    }
```

Unfortunately, it is returning all the records without filtering anything.
Where am I going wrong in this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: ES version: 6.7.0, NEST: 6.8

PS: I have integrated the logs with Nlog. So, now every day it inserts a new index with the date as the name. Here is a mapping for 219-06-28 (I am using the @timestamp):

```
{
    "logstash-2019-06-28": {
        "mappings": {
            "logevent": {
                "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "level": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "src": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "time": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch and NEST are you on? Could you share index mapping as well?

Comment: ES 6.7.0, NEST 6.8

Comment: Hi, I am very new to elastic search, how can I get index mapping? Thanks again for the reply :)

Comment: No worries, you can get index mapping simply using this GET request `http://localhost:9200/your_index_name_goes_here/_mapping`.

Comment: Thanks  Rob. I have integrated the logs with Nlog. So, now every day it inserts new index with the date as the name. But, I will attach one sample mapping for 2019-06-28 in the issue above. Thanks again!

Comment: `time` field has incorrect mapping, it's of type `text` but should be `date`, but maybe in your case you can just use existing date field `@timestamp`.

Comment: No no, you are correct. I just saw that I am using time and not the timestamp. Probably that is causing the issue. I will check it.

Comment: Hi Rob. I changed the mapping to timestamp. But, still, I am having the same issue. not filtering

Comment: Could you share updated mapping?

Comment: I did not change the mapping. Instead, I changed my query. Previously it was Field(f => f.time) . Now it is : .Field(f => f.timestamp)

Comment: But, now I see that it has no fields. Can it cause the problem?

Comment: Right, so the problem is in elasticsearch you have `@timestamp` but you are passing `timestamp` with NEST(`.Field(f => f.timestamp)`). Try changing to `.Field("@timestamp")` or you can mark `SearchEventDto.timestamp` with `Date` attribiute. You can read more about it in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/attribute-mapping.html).

Comment: @Rob your last comment should be an answer :)

Comment: Rob, Thanks for the clarification :) . but,  .Field("@timestamp") not working, so, I might go with the other option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post what we have figured out in comments as an answer as I think there are couple things which could be improved to increase performance and readability.

Solution:

Query from the question was using `.Field(f => f.timestamp)` which was translated by NEST to use `timestamp` field not `@timestamp`. Simple change to `.Field("@timestamp")` would resolve the problem as this is the proper field name in index mapping.

```
{
    "logstash-2019-06-28": {
        "mappings": {
            "logevent": {
                "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    ..
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We could also mark `timestamp` property with `PropertyName` attribute to tell NEST to use `@timestamp` as a name instead of `timestamp`

```
 public class SearchEventDto : IDto
    {
        [KendoColumn(Order = 1, DisplayName = "Timestamp", UIType = UIType.DateTime)]
        [PropertyName("@timestamp")]
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

    }
```

and query

```
var query = client.Search<SearchEventDto>(s => s
                .AllIndices()
                .AllTypes()
                .Query(q => q
                    .MatchAll() && +q
                    .DateRange(r =>r
                        .Field(f => f.timestamp)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2019,06,01, 0, 0, 0))
                    )
                )
            );
```

would be just working as well.

Improvements:

**Query only specific indices:**

```
var query = client.Search<SearchEventDto>(s => s
        .AllIndices()
        .AllTypes()
        ..
```

By using `AllIndices()` we are telling elasticsearch to try to gather documents from all of the indices, we could change it a little bit to query only indices with logs data:

```
var query = client.Search<SearchEventDto>(s => s
                .Index("logstash-*")
                .Type("logevent")
                ..
```

**Use filter context for date range filter:**

```
.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Filter(f => f.DateRange(..))))
```

This way your query should be faster as it doesn't care about calculating search relevance score. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-filter-context.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, thanks a lot for the extra tips for indices :) :)